# Local reverse/duplicate image search for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, photos, graphics, search

I'm searching for an application to find duplicate images.

In my Linux days, there was a nice Gtk+ application which I could provide some folders and which would list all duplicate images based on some algorithm to determine image-equality (It could detect duplicate images even if one image had a lower resolution or was color shifted)
It was also possible to modify the threshold to prevent false-positives.

So far, I found nothing for Mac OS X which could do this.

Nice GUI is a plus.

Comment: I realize that it's off-topic, but what was the name of the Linux app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dupeguru picture ed is free and does exactly that. http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22724/dupeguru-picture-edition

Comment: Very good! How can I move duplicates to trash? The only option I can find is "Move to trash and replace with hardlinks". Do I miss something? Edit: Please ignore. Just found it. It's the first option.

Comment: Another option is a paid app called ['PhotoBrain'](http://www.kandalu.net/products/photobrain/) - does the same thing as dupeGuru PE but is just a bit fancier with its UX including allowing you to specify the image to search for dupes for (within what folder)...